# add certificate to IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have to add certificate to IIS 6.0. But there are many other websites which runs unser default website. If I add certificate to default web site, will other site access will still remain in HHTP?
I only want to configure only one site to run on HTTPS..

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add the SSL certificate on the default website so long as you don't force the sites to use SSL from the IIS panel.

What you can do instead is **enable both HTTP or HTTPS** for the default site, but then use a redirect for the site you want to be secure that **redirects any unsecured traffic to the secured version**.

If someone tries to access another page in the default site, they may end up with a certificate error if the domains do not match.

Also a note on certificates, if you are having issues, make sure that the user the app pool is running as has permission to access the private key of the certificate. IIS might do this by default if you generate/import the certs through it's admin.